# Need to convert SQL column from varchar(255) to bigint(20)

Tags: mysql, sql, casting

The 'thread' column in an old Drupal 4.7 Comments table is varchar(255), and I need to convert it to bigint(20) to make it work for the 'comment_parent' column in a Wordpress wp_comments table.

I've tried various Cast and Convert commands I've seen and always get syntax errors.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: Chris is running MySQL 5.0.91 - see comments on Dan's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in **SQL Server**:

```
create table Comments 
(
    [thread] nvarchar(255)
) 

insert comments 
select '1' 
union select '2' 
union select '3' 
union select '4' 
union select '5' 
union select 'x' 

select 
    case 
        when ISNUMERIC([thread]) > 0 
            then CAST([thread] as bigint) 
        else 
            null 
    end colAsBigInt 
    , [thread] colAsNvarChar 
from comments
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/337eb/1

For **MySQL** try:

```
create table if not exists Comments 
(
    thread varchar(255) character set UTF8 not null
);

insert comments(thread) values ('1');
insert comments(thread) values ('2');
insert comments(thread) values ('3');
insert comments(thread) values ('4');
insert comments(thread) values ('5');
insert comments(thread) values ('6.1');
insert comments(thread) values ('x');

select 
    case 
        when thread  REGEXP ('^(-|\\+)?([0-9]+\\.[0-9]*|[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)$') 
            then cast(thread as signed)
        else 
            null 
    end colAsBigInt 
    , thread colAsVarChar 
from comments

--regex trick from here: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,1907,241284#msg-241284
--without the regex you'll get 0s instead of nulls for invalid values
--MySQL's cast only works on certain data types, given here http://www.roseindia.net/sql/mysql-example/mysql-cast.shtml
```

Runnable MySQL sample here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d848/9

Comment: Thanks - but I can't run this as is, right? Where (and how) do I plug in the table name (comments) and the column name (thread)?

`declare comments table ([thread] nvarchar(255))
insert comments
select '1'
union select '2'
union select '3'
union select '4'
union select '5'
union select 'x'

select case 
        when ISNUMERIC([thread]) > 0 
            then CAST([thread] as bigint) 
        else null 
    end colAsBigInt
, [thread] colAsNvarChar
from comments`

Comment: Your converted code works perfectly - I've updated the above example code to match yours.  It's only the select statement at the end that's really of interest - creating and inserting into the table was just to setup the data (I'd used a table variable in my original example just because that's easier than creating and dropping tables when writing example code - but in your case you'd have an actual table).  The key bit in the above is the case statement and the use of IsNumeric before casting, to ensure that whatever you cast can be cast before casting it; thus avoiding errors.

Comment: I just spotted in another comment thread that you're on MySQL - see second example.

Comment: @FahimParkar: just took a closer look at your link and spotted the rounding issue - that doesn't occur in SQL so I suspect it's a SQL Fiddle bug.  You may want to report it to JakeFeasel.

Answer (score 1):

when I ran that second set of code you provided for MySQL, it didn't convert that column to BigInt. It did give a side-by-side comparison of the colasBigInt and colasVarChar. Without exception, for thousands of rows, all colasBigInt read as Null, regardless of the colasVarChar value.

Answer (score 0):

What are the syntax errors you are getting? What database are you using?

The more information that you can give, the more likely it is that someone can help you.

Comment: Errors are like : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ...

database is MySQL - 5.0.91-log
I'm trying to run these commands in phpMyAdmin